# Lighttpd can't get files mounted via sshfs

Tags: lighttpd, centos6, sshfs

I've got a **CentoOS 6** server with a directory mounted via **sshfs** from my Mac directory:

```
sshfs -o allow_other dmitri@10.211.55.2:/Users/dmitri/Sites /var/www/html
```

but when I try to start lighttpd server, I get an error:

```
Starting lighttpd: 2013-11-20 10:34:43: (configfile.c.989) opening configfile  /var/www/html/www.example.ru/public/_engine/lighttpd.conf failed: Permission denied
```

Lighttpd user is **lighttpd**, BUT when I'm swithing to user lighttpd:

```
su lighttpd -s /bin/bash
```

I can read any files in mounted directory:

```
bash-4.1$ whoami
lighttpd
bash-4.1$ cat /var/www/html/www.example.ru/public/_engine/lighttpd.conf
server.error-handler-404 = "/zf2.php/404"
...
```

I can't understand why it happens and how to make lighttpd work.

PS (mb it would be useful):

```
bash-4.1$ whoami
lighttpd
bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/www/html/www.example.ru/public/_engine
bash-4.1$ ls -lh
-rw-r--r--. 1 501 games 2,3K Ноя 15 09:48 account-pages.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 501 games  23K Ноя 15 09:48 admin-pages.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual troublemaker was **SELinux**. All the troubles have been solved by disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give lighttpd permission to access the files. Unmount the file system, run the following command to give lighttpd ownership of your web directory, then mount the files system again.

```
Chown -R lighttpd:lighttpd /var/www/html
```